# How to join two pandas DataFrames on trailing part of path / filename

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two data Frames as follows.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'PATH':[r'C:\FODLER\Test1.jpg',
                            r'C:\A\FODLER\Test2.jpg',
                            r'C:\A\FODLER\Test3.jpg',
                            r'C:\A\FODLER\Test4.jpg'],
                    'VALUE':[45,23,45,2]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'F_NAME': [r'FODLER\Test1.jpg',
                               r'FODLER\Test2.jpg',
                               r'FODLER\Test6.jpg',
                               r'FODLER\Test3.jpg',
                               r'FODLER\Test4.jpg',
                               r'FODLER\Test9.jpg'],
                    'VALUE_X': ['12', '25', '97', '33', '123', '0'],
                    'CORDS': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']})
```

I want to join df2, where PATH.Contains(F_NAME) to df1 table.
so resulting data frame is as follows :

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'PATH':[r'C:\FODLER\Test1.jpg',
                            r'C:\A\FODLER\Test2.jpg',
                            r'C:\A\FODLER\Test3.jpg',
                            r'C:\A\FODLER\Test4.jpg'],
                    'F_NAME': [r'FODLER\Test1.jpg',
                               r'FODLER\Test2.jpg',
                               r'FODLER\Test3.jpg',
                               r'FODLER\Test4.jpg'],
                    'VALUE_X': ['12', '25', '33', '123'],
                    'CORDS': ['1', '2', '4', '5'],
                    'VALUE':[45,23,45,2]})
```

How do I write the pandas merge statement to do this joining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with a regex using [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the end-of-line anchored part of the path:

```
import re

pattern = f"({'|'.join(df2['F_NAME'].apply(re.escape))})$"

df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1['PATH'].str.extract(pattern, expand=False),
                right_on='F_NAME', how='left')
```

Output:

```
                    PATH  VALUE            F_NAME VALUE_X CORDS
0    C:\FODLER\Test1.jpg     45  FODLER\Test1.jpg      12     1
1  C:\A\FODLER\Test2.jpg     23  FODLER\Test2.jpg      25     2
2  C:\A\FODLER\Test3.jpg     45  FODLER\Test3.jpg      33     4
3  C:\A\FODLER\Test4.jpg      2  FODLER\Test4.jpg     123     5
```

`pattern`:

```
(FODLER\\Test1\.jpg|FODLER\\Test2\.jpg|FODLER\\Test6\.jpg|FODLER\\Test3\.jpg|FODLER\\Test4\.jpg|FODLER\\Test9\.jpg)$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tFHVYd/1)

---

Alternatively, if the `PATH` only has 2 components (`folder\filename.ext`), you can assign a column with the trailing part of the path before merging:

```
df3 = (df1
    .assign(F_NAME=df1['PATH'].str.extract(r'([^\\]+\\[^\\]+)$', expand=False))
    .merge(df2, how='left')
)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KHtPRF/1)

Comment: This is new to me, and thanks for the clarification. It works excellently. !

Comment: I hadn't realised you could use formulas in `left_on` and `right_on`.TIL

Comment: @Nick you can pass any array-like, it's quite useful, then you don't have to assign a column ;)

Comment: How to eliminate case sensitivity here ?

Comment: @PCG transform both series with `str.casefold` before merging

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one:

```
df3 = df1[df1['PATH'].str.contains('|'.join(df2['F_NAME']))].merge(df2, left_on=df1['PATH'], right_on=df2['F_NAME'], how='left')


print(df3)
```

Comment: Have you tested the code? I don't think it's working

Comment: This is not working. "error: bad escape \T at position 6"